How do I extract a list of conditional formatting rules from excel using the xml?
I need to extract a list of all cells that have conditional formatting, where they might be highlighted yellow as a result of conditional formatting. I have tried using openxpyxl to do this, but it will only give me a list of all cells that have a conditional formatting rules, regardless of whether the rule might result in a yellow, red, blue, etc highlight. I am unable to us pywin32 or xlwings to do this as they run too slowly.
Current openpyxl code:
wb_openpyxl = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
ws_openpyxl = wb_openpyxl["Sheet1"]
for cf in ws_openpyxl.conditional_formatting:
     print(cf)

#<ConditionalFormatting A5:A9>

Desired result:
Conditional formatting A5:A9 if a5>0, (hex color associated with yellow)

You need an application like Excel to apply the conditional formats to get the evaluated colours.

The are mostly simple rules like "highlight yellow if the cell is blank", so I'm planning to use openpyxl to see the formula & color, and then also use open pyxl ot see if the cell value is blank

The following will extract the CF details with some formatting depending on the actual rule used.
Colours are Hex by default but could be cross matched if you wante to see 'yellow' rather than 'FFFF00' but seems the hex is OK.
from openpyxl import load_workbook


wb_openpyxl = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
ws_openpyxl = wb_openpyxl["Sheet1"]

print('')
cs_list = ['Start', 'End']
for cf in ws_openpyxl.conditional_formatting:
    print(f"Conditional Format Range: {cf.cells}")
    print("Rules")
    for rule in cf.cfRule:
        if rule.colorScale:
            print(f"Rule: {rule.priority}: Color Scale")
            for idx, cs in enumerate(rule.colorScale.cfvo):
                print(f'{cs_list[idx]}: _Type: {cs.type} _Value: {cs.val} _Color: {rule.colorScale.color[idx].rgb[2:]}')
        else:
            print(f"Rule: {rule.priority}: Formula")
            print(f"Operation: {'Use a formula' if rule.operator is None else f'Format {rule.operator}'} "
                  f"{str(rule.formula)[1:-1]} "
                  f"Stop if True: {'Disabled' if rule.stopIfTrue is None else 'Enabled'}")
            print(f"bfColor: {rule.dxf.fill.bgColor.rgb[2:]}")
            print(f"endColor: {rule.dxf.fill.end_color.rgb[2:]}")
            print(f"fgColor: {rule.dxf.fill.fgColor.rgb[2:]}")
        print('-----------------------')

